# Do I need to upgrade only the RAM for making Ubuntu's virtual machine quick and smooth as OS X at the same time?

Tags: graphics, vmware, ram, macosx, mac-mini

I own a Mac mini Mid 2011. My Mac mini's details:

- 8GB RAM DDR3 1333
- Intel Core i5 2,3 GHz
- Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB

I have Ubuntu 14.10 and OS X 10.10 partitions with modified rEFInd, but it's very annoying to change the keyboards (PC keyboard to Apple keyboard and vice-versa). I use PC keyboard to press <kbd>ALT</kbd> to start Linux and when I want to start OS X, firstly I have to use PC keyboard to start OSes list and when I start OS X, I have to switch to Apple keyboard. OS X and Ubuntu can't read themselves the files.

I want to remove Ubuntu 14.10 from the partition and install Ubuntu 14.04 as a virtual machine at OS X with VMWAre Fusion and install Cinnamon and Docky.

I use Ubuntu for:

- FontForge (font editor);
- Converting ttx via terminal;
- Building and modify the icons and the themes;
- Developing in Inkscape;
- Building the Conky widgets;

Now, do I need to upgrade only the RAM for making Ubuntu's virtual machine quick and smooth as OS X at the same time? Are processor and graphics required for upgrade too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to upgrade any hardware in order to comfortably run a virtual instance of Ubuntu on that, but more RAM is never a bad thing.

Comment: So, I gave 2 or 4GB to one Ubuntu's machine and OS X stayed with 4 or 2GB (5GB of RAM was consumed by OS X) and without nothing to do, almost 95% of 8GB RAM of OS X and Ubuntu was consumed.

Comment: Memory is there to be used. Ubuntu runs well on 2GB RAM and OS X should run well on 6GB RAM. Consumption, however, means different things. It's desirable to use 100% RAM, otherwise, some RAM is doing nothing. But the fact that RAM is used, doesn't mean it's unavailable. Lots are used for caches and buffers. That will be reclaimed when necessary. But yes, the Ubuntu VM will constantly occupy the amount of RAM you've given it, from an OS X perspective. Ubuntu, however, will not use all of that unless it has to.

Comment: if I want to upgrade the RAM memory to 16GB, will my Ubuntu virtual machine and my OS X be so quick at the same time?

Comment: It depends on how you use them.

Comment: I use Ubuntu for developing the SVG and the fonts in Inkscape and the fonts in FontForge. I use Ubuntu to build the icons and the themes for Gnome.

Comment: Well, I use Ubuntu guests with 2GB RAM for that type of thing with no issue. If you think it's slow, then it's more likely to do with GPU than CPU. Perhaps you'd like to try using a different desktop than Unity.